# Get total duration with avplayer in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, avplayer

I want to find the total duration of online song using AvPlayer. I have googled it but does'nt get any relevant answer. Please suggest me...

Comment: try this `self.player.currentItem.asset.duration;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get duration using AVPlayer like this

> ```
> DLog(@"%d",(int) AvPlayer.duration);
> _duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (int)p.duration / 60, (int)p.duration % 60, nil];
> ```

Comment: This give me "nan" instead of duration......this method give duration for offline song not online .

Comment: It can give you data about online song too,If you are using NSData to play songs.

Comment: If you show your code for online song I can help in a better way.

Comment: AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.com/download.php?id=401007"] options:nil];
    CMTime time = audioAsset.duration;
    
    NSLog(@"dur is %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(o));

Comment: I have try it with AVPLayer & AvpLayer.currentIem also but no results.

Comment: NSData *songData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:songData error:nil];
    self.player.numberOfLoops=0;
    _player.delegate=self;
    [_player prepareToPlay];
Then print duration of song as i have mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Yes you are correct. this is the right way to find durtion of online song. Actually i'm only trying with AVPlayer as it is mainly used to play online songs. thanks

Comment: well...this method (AVAudioPlayer) stuck the UI until song gets download from the server. I want to find asynchronously total duration of online song. If anybody can help then please.

Comment: @new_user You can put this method on new thread and can interact with the app without any confliction.